# How can you dynamically generate list items to an unordered list in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have an error panel that is subbed in to a page if an error goes wrong to gracefully handle and display errors.  Currently, I am just appending the error messages to a string and pushing that to a label.  If you have multiple errors, this gets messy.  Therefore, I'd like to push each error to a list item in a bulleted, unordered list.

How can I dynamically generate, from a vb codebehind file, new list items inside of an undordered list element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not use a [`BulletedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx) control? This control will render an unordered list to the client.

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList" runat="Server" BulletStyle="NotSet">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

You can then add list items programmatically from code behind like this.

```
BulletedList.Items.Add("Item1");
```

You can also accomplish this by adding `runat='server'` to reference the `UL` tag server side.

```
<ul id="uList" runat="server">
</ul>
```

Then in the code behind use the `InnerHtml` property to programmatically add `LI` tags to the contents within the opening and closing `UL` tags.

```
uList.InnerHtml += "<li>Item1</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a page level variable to hold the errors, like a list or an array.  Then just write a method that does something like:

```
Private Sub WriteErrors()
  lblErrors.txt = "<ul>"
  For Each s as String in _myErrors
   me.lblErrors.Text &= "<li>" & s & "</li>"
  End For
  lblErrors.Text &= "</ul>" 
End Sub
```